# Shopify Query for Cart Attributes

Tags: attributes, shopify, cart

I have a cart attribute to determine which charity a portion of sales proceeds are sent to. I have successfully added the attribute. I would like to know how to go about running a month end report of orders with the cart attribute listed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A cart attribute gets shown as an order attribute. Simply examine any order in your shop to see the attributes. You can then run any kind of report you want by extracting those. Add a .json to any order in your admin to see the exact fields of interest.